# Git submodules vs subtrees vs branches - how to choose the right one in a directory structure

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have a private `Git` repo with the following structure:
[image: Structure_now]
`A` is the root directory and the remaining are the subdirectories. There is only one branch - `master` as of now.

All of the code is meant to be run on `Windows` platform. Now, I had migrated `D` to `Linux` and to categorize/group logically, I planned the following structure:
[image: Structure_planned]

Here, the purpose of non-leaf nodes added is categorization and nothing much. The executables are all present in leaf nodes.

I would like to make my repo organized in such a way that I should be able to fetch:

1. `D` separately (programs that run only on `Linux`).
2. `E`, `F`, `H`, `G`, `I` together (programs that run only on `Windows`).
3. `E`, `F`, `H` together (logically grouped programs).
4. `G`, `I` together (logically grouped programs).

Of the above, only 1 and 3 are likely to be (or worthy of being) branched and merged.

I am pretty new to `Git` and happened to read about `submodules`, `subtrees`, `branches` but would like to know from developers from their experience their opinion about the best way to structure it. Is this a good structure or does it require any changes?

Comment: I think, unfortunately, "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise," and thus this question is off-topic. That said, I'll offer this comment (my opinion). Submodules are probably your best bet as they will allow you to pick and choose what you clone (subtrees will not). Branches are not a good solution to this problem. Edit: that said, submodules are not without their own troubles. I would recommend simply not having this setup—use one repository per software component until that poses an actual problem.